# Storage a big csv (27 mb) in internal storage in android

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

I need storages a big csv (27 mb) in internal storage in android (with kotlin). All csv data must be stored. 
After storagehave i need list all of data in an activity (for example in recyclerView)
What is the best way  for make this?

Comment: Without knowing what you plan to do with it, we can't know how to store it.  Are you reading it and iterating?  Are you searching for specific rows?  Something else?  The first would line up with keeping it a file, the second with a db.  You need to give more context.

Comment: In internal storage? In database? Line for line?

Comment: I updated the question. I hope I have been more enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this helpfull](https://www.genuitec.com/dump-a-stringbuilder-to-file/)

If you want to have a SQL Database, then its is best to use [room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

With Android 11 you will be forced to use scoped storage. The old way of asking permissions will not work then.

You can use something like this. The user will be able to see the file for himself with the standart File App

```
//opens the File App that is already installed on every Android Device
//it will always save the file in the download folder
//use this start the activity for the File App
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
intent.type = "text/plain"
//user can change the name how he likes later on 
//this is just a suggestion for the name
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "myCSVFile.csv")
startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
```

When the user clicked OK in the File App

```
override fun onActivityResult(request:Int, result:Int, resultData: Intent?){
if(resultData != null && resultData.data != null){
    //this is the URI for the file that the File App has created
    val fUri = resultData.data!!

    //get the file descriptor
    val pfd: ParcelFileDescriptor = applicationContext.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(fUri, "w")!!
    //create write stream
    val bW = FileOutputStream(pfd.fileDescriptor)

    //first line of csv file
    bW.write(csvHeader.toByteArray())

    //best if these 2 lines are in a loop
    //the string should not be bigger then 100bytes, 
    //I have run into exceptions where it said the parcel size was to big
    bW.write("\n something something something".toByteArray())
    bW.flush()

    bW.close()
}
```

}